# How to get the difference between First column First value and First column Last value in result set of a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am getting result set for the below query

```
SELECT
   CAST(SUM(CASE
               WHEN  S.TAXABLEAMT <=2000 THEN (S.INVOICEQTY)
            ELSE NULL END) AS DECIMAL(30,2)) AS QTY ,
    YEAR(S.invoicedate) YEAR1,Month(S.invoicedate) MNTH  
FROM
    SALESDATA S
where
   month(S.invoicedate) BETWEEN 1AND 4  and year(S.invoicedate) BETWEEN  2009 AND 2010  
GROUP BY
   YEAR(S.invoicedate),Month(S.invoicedate)
ORDER BY
   YEAR(S.invoicedate),Month(S.invoicedate)
```

as

```
QTY        MONTH/YEAR
250            01/2010
238            02/2010
450            03/2010
238            04/2010
150            05/2010
238            05/2010
650            06/2010
238            07/2010
250            08/2010
238            09/2010
250            10/2010
238            11/2010
250            12/2010
238            01/2009
250            01/2009
238            02/2009
450            03/2009
238            04/2009
```

Now I want difference between QTY of First column First value(i.e.250) and First column Last value(i.e.238 )    in result set

as Separate column.(i.e. only single value ).

Is it possible?(with Separate  table or within same table in the query)

Regards,

NSJ

Comment: Just a note for the future - in a `CASE` expression, if no `WHEN` clause matches, the result is NULL. So your `ELSE NULL` part is redundant.

Comment: Also, when posting code, please highlight the code, and format it (use the {} button above the question textbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample code that does what you want using a cte.

```
declare @T table (id int identity, value int)

insert into @T values (10)
insert into @T values (20)
insert into @T values (30)

;with cte(id, value)
as (select id, value from @T)
select 
  id,
  value,
  (select top 1 value
   from cte
   order by id desc) - 
  (select top 1 value
   from cte
   order by id asc) as Diff
from cte
```

Here is your query using cte. This is not tested at all since I do not have your tables or data.

```
with cte(qty, year1, mnth)
as
(select
   cast(sum(case
            when  s.taxableamt <=2000
            then (s.invoiceqty)
            else null end) as decimal(30,2)) as qty ,
   year(s.invoicedate) year1,
   month(s.invoicedate) mnth  
 from
   salesdata s
 where
   month(s.invoicedate) between 1 and 4 and
   year(s.invoicedate) between  2009 and 2010  
 group by
   year(s.invoicedate),
   month(s.invoicedate)
)
select
  qty,
  year1,
  mnth,
  (select top 1 qty from cte order by year1, mnth desc) - 
    (select top 1 qty from cte order by year1, mnth asc) as diff
from cte    
order by year1, mnth
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN S.TAXABLEAMT <=2000 THEN (S.INVOICEQTY) ELSE NULL END) AS DECIMAL(30,2)) AS QTY ,
YEAR(S.invoicedate) YEAR1,Month(S.invoicedate) MNTH,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Year(invoicedate),Month(invoicedate)) as rn,
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Year(invoicedate),Month(invoicedate)) as descrn into #temp
FROM SALESDATA S
where month(S.invoicedate) BETWEEN 1AND 4 and year(S.invoicedate) BETWEEN 2009 AND 2010 
GROUP BY YEAR(S.invoicedate),Month(S.invoicedate)
ORDER BY YEAR(S.invoicedate),Month(S.invoicedate)

declare @diffAmt int = (select top 1 Qty from #temp where rn = 1) - (select top 1 Qty from #temp where descrn = 1)
select *,@diffAmt as DiffAmt from #temp
```